# V8 garbage collector failures

Tags: node.js, garbage-collection, v8

we're trying to limit a memory consumption of our node.js apps with "--max_old_space_size" to force a full GC run before the app reaches the default 1.5G limit. But we're fighting with occasional GC failures, eg:

```
*** glibc detected *** builder-content-processor: double free or corruption (!prev): 0x00000000066d3b90 ***
======= Backtrace: =========
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6(+0x7da26)[0x7f2952678a26]
builder-content-processor(_ZN2v88internal4Heap20FreeDeadArrayBuffersEb+0xc6)[0xace2b6]
builder-content-processor(_ZN2v88internal20MarkCompactCollector11SweepSpacesEv+0x15f)[0xaf70bf]
builder-content-processor(_ZN2v88internal20MarkCompactCollector14CollectGarbageEv+0x48)[0xb00e28]
builder-content-processor(_ZN2v88internal4Heap11MarkCompactEv+0x60)[0xab76e0]
builder-content-processor(_ZN2v88internal4Heap24PerformGarbageCollectionENS0_16GarbageCollectorENS_15GCCallbackFlagsE+0x318)[0xaceff8]
builder-content-processor(_ZN2v88internal4Heap14CollectGarbageENS0_16GarbageCollectorEPKcS4_NS_15GCCallbackFlagsE+0x239)[0xacf599]
builder-content-processor(_ZN2v88internal4Heap15HandleGCRequestEv+0xa1)[0xacffa1]
builder-content-processor(_ZN2v88internal10StackGuard16HandleInterruptsEv+0x31c)[0xa6bddc]
builder-content-processor(_ZN2v88internal18Runtime_StackGuardEiPPNS0_6ObjectEPNS0_7IsolateE+0x2b)[0xca191b]
[0x3b64b90963b]
```

Full backtrace and memory map: http://pastebin.com/PtGNmVV2

Any ideas? Node 4.4.4

Answer (score 1):

Update: it seems to be caused by an outdated version of *nan* package  1.8.x which is used in *bson* package 0.2.x (a dependency of *mongodb* package 1.4.x)